# Printing Specific Part of HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I know this question has an Already been asked but I am using Different and Short Approach.

I have print button for printing Invoice in my web page

```
<button class="print" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

The Problem is it prints the whole document including `print` button 
is their any way to exclude `print` button from printing in document

Checkout this Link : https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-add-a-print-button-4072006

Comment: You can set custom CSS for when the user is printing to hide different parts of the page just google "css print style" https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have to add

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">`

in my head part of the page

---

print.css is as below

```
body {visibility:hidden;}
```

`.print {visibility:visible;}`

---

Also we had to assign `class="print"` to  to html element which we want to print

Thanks to @Clay

Answer (score 0):

change *onclick* function like this

`<button class="print" onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';window.print();">Print</button>`

Comment: would work, but not a great solution.